# How can I get my app running with InstantRails 1.0 on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I'm trying to get my application to run on InstantRails 1.0.  The application works fine using WeBrick, but when I try to run it using Apache in InstantRails, I get:

```
[Wed May 26 12:26:53 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] couldn't spawn child process: c:/instantrails-1.0/rails_apps/guest/public/dispatch.cgi
```

In the apache error log, and my browser shows:

```
Application error
Rails application failed to start properly"
```

The cookbook application that comes with InstantRails works just fine.

My apache config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName guest.havelick.com
# handle all requests through SCGI
SCGIMount /dispatch.fcgi 127.0.0.1:9999
DocumentRoot ${path}/rails_apps/guest/public
<Directory ${path}/rails_apps/guest/public>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

and the SCGI port matches that which I am using in the InstantRails config.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: i would advise not to use InstantRails. It is filled with all ancient versions. You should get ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org, for development on Windows.

Comment: I'm actually using old versions on purpose.  I can only use technology from early 2006 for this project :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The default .htaccess file has:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.cgi [QSA,L]
```

Whereas InstantRails expects:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```